# C# trouble with use of class and listbox

Tags: c#, class, listbox

Create a Visual C# application that displays the contents of the Teams.txt file in a ListBox control. When the user selects a team in the ListBox, the application should display the number of times that team has won the World Series in the time period from 1903 to 2012.

The two files used are Teams.txt , which contains a list of the names of teams that have won the Championship at least once, and WorldSeriesWinners.txt - this file contains a chronological list of the World Series winning teams from 1903 - 2012. The first line in the file is the nae of the team that won in 1903 and the last line is the name of the team that won in 2012. Note that the World Series was not played in 1904 or 1994.
**This is the question that i'm having problems with. Actually in this question I must make use of class, but the code is not working**

**This is my code. I hope that you can help me find the problem**
**This is the class part**

```
class WorldSeries
{
    // Field
    private string _wins;    // The team's total number of wins.

    // Constructor
    public WorldSeries()
    {
        _wins = "";
    }

    // Wins property
    public string Wins
    {
        get { return _wins; }
        set { _wins = value; }
    }
}
```

**This is the rest of my code**

```
    // Variables
    string teamName;                    // To hold the teams names.


    private void ReadTeams()
    {
        try
        {
            // Local Variables
            StreamReader inputTeams;    //To read the file

            // Open the Teams.txt file.
            inputTeams = File.OpenText("Teams.txt");

            // Read the file's contents.
            while (!inputTeams.EndOfStream)
            {
                // Read a line and add it to the ListBox.
                teamName = inputTeams.ReadLine();
                lst_teams.Items.Add(teamName);
            }
            // Close the file.
            inputTeams.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display an error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void GetTeamWin (WorldSeries worldSeries)
    {
        try
        {
            //Local Variables
            int index=0;      // Loop counter, initialized to 0.
            int winCount = 0; // Accumulator, initialized to 0.

            // Open the WorldSeriesWinners.txt file.
            StreamReader inputFile=File.OpenText
            ("WorldSeriesWinners.txt")

            // Create a List object to hold strings.
            List<string> winnerList = new List<string>();

            // Read the file's contents
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                // Read a line and add it to the list.
                winnerList.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
            }

            // Sort the items in the List.
            winnerList.Sort();

            while (index >=0)
            {
                // Search the team name in the List
                index = winnerList.BinarySearch(teamName);
                winCount++;

                // Remove the team name from the List
                winnerList.RemoveAt(index);
            }

            // Store the total number of wins of the team in the Wins
            // parameter.
            worldSeries.Wins = winCount.ToString();

            // Clear the List
            winnerList.Clear();

            // Display the number of times the team has won.
            lbl_results.Text = "The" + lst_teams.SelectedItem.ToString()                        
            + "has won the World Series" +
            winCount + "time(s), between 1903 and 2012.";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display an error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the file.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is simple, you must count the number of times each team appears on the file, nothing else, it doesn't matters if a year had no tournament.

Answer (score 0):

The number of teams wins is easily small enough to hold in memory. You can read the whole file once and store a dictionary of the team name to the number of wins in memory. Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> numberOfWins =
                    File.ReadAllLines("WorldSeriesWinners.txt")
                    .GroupBy(t => t)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count() );
```

You could then have simple function that checked if the selected team was in this list and returned the no of wins if so, if not, zero:

```
private int GetNoOfWins(string teamName)
{
    if (numberOfWins.ContainsKey(teamName))
    {
        return numberOfWins[teamName];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

which could easily be used in your existing code:

```
int winCount = GetNoOfWins(lst_teams.SelectedItem.ToString());
lbl_results.Text = "The" + lst_teams.SelectedItem.ToString()
            + "has won the World Series" +
            winCount + "time(s), between 1903 and 2012.";
```